# Subtract big number in bash

Tags: bash, terminal

I Want to do a sub with two big number

my purpose is

1805334111369276485744644020321551471447190030955050085289-3369574570478873127315415525946742317481702644901195284480

I try with

```
echo $((1805334111369276485744644020321551471447190030955050085289-3369574570478873127315415525946742317481702644901195284480))
```

My result is:
3160661815551241129

but it's not correct.

I can do the similar operation in console chrome
and I Have

```
-1.5642404591095965e+
```

How can I do this operation in bash?
I tried even with `expr`, but without lucky

It's ok to check if a number is greater then another

in shell

```
echo $((1805334111369276485744644020321551471447190030955050085289>3369574570478873127315415525946742317481702644901195284480))
```

result: 1

same operation in chrome

```
1805334111369276485744644020321551471447190030955050085289>3369574570478873127315415525946742317481702644901195284480
```

result:false

And chrome is right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ARITHMETIC EVALUATION` section of `bash`'s manual explains why you get this result with `$((...))` :

> Evaluation is done in fixed-width integers with  no  check  for  overflow

You may be able to use `expr` (depending on compile-time options, check [@Benjamin W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3266847/)'s comment), but you need spaces between the operator and its operands :

```
$ expr 1805334111369276485744644020321551471447190030955050085289 - 3369574570478873127315415525946742317481702644901195284480
-1564240459109596641570771505625190846034512613946145199191
```

As [@PesaThe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6176817) mentions you can also use `bc`, one of its main features being able to handle arbitrary precision arithmetics :

```
bc <<< "1805334111369276485744644020321551471447190030955050085289 - 3369574570478873127315415525946742317481702644901195284480"
-1564240459109596641570771505625190846034512613946145199191
```

Comment: Notice that the precision of GNU `expr` is subject to how it was compiled (see [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#expr-invocation)): "When built with support for the GNU MP library, expr uses arbitrary-precision arithmetic; otherwise, it uses native arithmetic types and may fail due to arithmetic overflow." To get guaranteed arbitrary precision, you could use bc.

Comment: Yep, getting `Numerical result out of range` on my system.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thanks, I've made my first statement less categorical

Comment: You might add the `bc` solution to your answer to make it complete :)

Comment: @PesaThe I'm not familiar enough with `bc`, is it guaranteed to work whichever the system architecture and compile time options?

Comment: @Aaron According to Benjamin, it is guaranteed. I am not enough familiar with `bc` to tell you that for sure. Though `bc` works on my system whereas `expr` does not.

Comment: thanks guys, with expr I have this message. I use mac and I try in zsh and even in bash, with `bc` works! What does mean three arrow before bc ?

Comment: @monkeyUser The `<<<` is bash's herestring syntax. More info [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76402/command-line-instead-of)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Perl

```
$ perl -le ' BEGIN { use Math::BigInt; my $x=Math::BigInt->new("1805334111369276485744644020321551471447190030955050085289"); my $y=Math::BigInt->new("3369574570478873127315415525946742317481702644901195284480"); print $x->bsub($y) } '
-1564240459109596641570771505625190846034512613946145199191
$ perl -le ' BEGIN { use Math::BigInt; my $x=Math::BigInt->new("1805334111369276485744644020321551471447190030955050085289"); my $y=Math::BigInt->new("3369574570478873127315415525946742317481702644901195284480"); printf("%g\n",$x->bsub($y)) } '
-1.56424e+57
$
```

If you want to pass echo output to Perl, then

```
$ echo "1805334111369276485744644020321551471447190030955050085289-3369574570478873127315415525946742317481702644901195284480" | perl -ne ' BEGIN { use Math::BigInt } /(\d+)-(\d+)/; $x=Math::BigInt->new($1); $y=Math::BigInt->new($2); printf("%g\n",$x->bsub($y)) '
-1.56424e+57
$
```

As @PesaThe mentioned you can use `bc` also

```
$ bc <<< "1805334111369276485744644020321551471447190030955050085289-3369574570478873127315415525946742317481702644901195284480"
-1564240459109596641570771505625190846034512613946145199191
$
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're feeling adventurous you can use that good old `dc` (desk calculator, a cute RPN calculator):

```
dc <<< "1805334111369276485744644020321551471447190030955050085289 3369574570478873127315415525946742317481702644901195284480 - p"
```

Answer is: `-1564240459109596641570771505625190846034512613946145199191`

Answer (score 1):

Mac OSX `awk` can also handle big numbers:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print 1805334111369276485744644020321551471447190030955050085289 - \
3369574570478873127315415525946742317481702644901195284480}'
```

```
-1.56424045910959651912822682029e+57
```

Or by using `printf`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{printf "%.5e\n", 1805334111369276485744644020321551471447190030955050085289 - \
3369574570478873127315415525946742317481702644901195284480}'
```

```
-1.56424e+57
```

On the other hand **GNU awk** needs `-M` switch to support big numbers so use:

```
gawk -M 'BEGIN{print 1805334111369276485744644020321551471447190030955050085289 - \
3369574570478873127315415525946742317481702644901195284480}'
```